# Как сделать выпадающее меню для сайта?

Tags: html, css, ucoz

Здравствуйте. Хотел бы узнать, как сделать выпадающее меня для сайта (ucoz). Чтоб оно выпадало вниз вертикально путём наведения курсора. Шаблон вот такого дизайна ( http://manual.ucoz.net/publ/22-1-0-444). Я хочу, чтобы из верхних меню (красных, в верхнем правом углу) можно было сделать выпадающее меню в несколько подразделов. Вот код шапки:

```
<div id="header">
 <h1 id="site-logo">
 <!-- <logo> --><i><font face="Comic Sans MS" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 24pt; color: rgb(218, 165, 32);" size="6">Республиканская картинная галерея им. А.В. Лосева</font></i><!-- </logo> -->
 </h1>
 <div class="usermenu">
 <ul>
 <li>
 <a title="Главная" href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Главная<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>

<li>
 <a title="Выставки" href="http://bendery-art.ucoz.ru/index/0-2">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Выставки<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
<li>
 <a title="Мероприятия" href="http://bendery-art.ucoz.ru/faq">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Мероприятия<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
<li>
 <a title="Фотогалерея" href="http://bendery-art.ucoz.ru/photo">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Фотогалерея<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
<li>
 <a title="СОтрудники" href="http://bendery-art.ucoz.ru/publ">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Сотрудники<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
<li>
 <a title="История" href="http://bendery-art.ucoz.ru/blog">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Блог<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>    
 <li>
 <a title="Информация" href="http://bendery-art.ucoz.ru/index/0-2">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-home"><span><!--<s5176>-->Информация<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
 </li>
 <?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?>
 <li>
 <a title="Мой профиль" href="$PERSONAL_PAGE_LINK$">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-profile"><span><!--<s5214>-->Мой профиль<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a title="Выход" href="$LOGOUT_LINK$">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-log"><span><!--<s5164>-->Выход<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <?else?>
 <li>
 <a title="Регистрация" href="$REGISTER_LINK$">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-profile"><span><!--<s3089>-->Регистрация<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a title="Вход" href="$LOGIN_LINK$">
 <span class="tm-left"></span>
 <span class="tm-mid tm-log"><span><!--<s3087>-->Вход<!--</s>--></span></span>
 <span class="tm-right"></span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <?endif?>
 <?if($RSS_LINK$)?>
 <li> 
 </li>
 <?endif?>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <?if($SEARCH_FORM$)?>
 $SEARCH_FORM$
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <?endif?>
 </div>
```

Если сможете скинуть шаблон кода на выпадающее меню, которое я мог бы использовать, то был бы признателен. Спасибо. Жду комментариев

Comment: [Vertical CSS Menus][1]


  [1]: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/category/C2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нагдляный пример, http://jsfiddle.net/faaLU/2/ а дальше меняй его по себя